# How to pass predefined vector to let in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Let's say I have a vector defined like this:

```
(def v '[test 1])
```

How can I use this vector in a let statement? I want to do something like this:

```
(let v
   test)
```

and return `1`. Everything I've tried so far just gives me:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: let requires a vector for its binding in user:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it like that because let is a macro/special form that introduces bindings in its body. In normal clojure semantics var `v` can have any value at runtime and that would make it impossible to compile the let block. In other words, the bindings vector must be known and fixed at compile time. Also, since body of the let block is static, there is no reason to make the list of bindings variable.

The normal way of setting local bindings "dynamically" when evaluating "static" expressions is to use functions, i.e.

```
   (defn let-v [v]
      v)

   (def test 1)
   (let-v test)
```

If you want to generate let bindings (and probably also the let body), you'd need [a macro](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defmacro). Though [this sounds more like an X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So maybe you want to expand on *why* you think you need this construct if functions won't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to get at only the value of `1` (as in your sample):

As an extraction of the value in a function call - Add destructuring:

```
(def v [x 1])

(defn let-v 
  [[_ i]] 
    i)

(let-v v) ; => 1
```

Pretty much the same thing in a `let` statement:

```
(dev v [x 1])

(let [[_ i] v]
  i)
```

And, obviously, to pass the vector into a function but the destructure happens on the `let` within the function:

```
(def v [x 1])

(defn let-v
  [v]
  (let [[_ i] v]
    i))
```